# How to set image as background of div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to move the red circle image to the position shown as in below photo:
[image]

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>領収書</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    {% if receipt %}
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h2>領収書
                        </h2>
                    </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">
                                <h5>No.　{{receipt['receipt_number']}}</h5>
                        <h5>{{receipt['date']}}</h5>
                        <hr/>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                        <h3>{{receipt['c_name']}}　様</h3>
                        <hr/>
                    </div>

                </div>

             <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center">
                        <h3><b>￥ {{receipt['amount']}}</b><br/>
                        </h3>
                            <hr/>

                    <h3>
                        但 {{receipt['quantity']}} {{receipt['product']}}<br/>
                    </h3>
                        <h4>
                        上記正に領収いたしました
                    </h4>
                    </div>


                </div>





        </div>
        <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-xs-offset-6">
                        <h5>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h5>
                        <h5>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h5>
                        <img src='inkan.PNG'/>
                    </div>
                </div>


    </div>
     {% endif %}
    <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: `div{background:url(path_to_image)}`?

Comment: Learn html and css! http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the image as a background, like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center col-xs-offset-6" style="background:url(urlhere) no-repeat">
```

Refer to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background_shorthand) for more info.

Comment: thanks, but I got so many red circles if I do like that: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/Capture3.JPG

Comment: thanks. But when I tried to print the web page in Chrome, the red circle is not shown up.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these style to your img and play with "right" value;

`<img src='inkan.PNG' style="position: absolute; right: 200px;"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an `id` and then add it ad css property `background: url({url});` like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myDiv {
    background: url({url});
}
```

Include that CSS code either from a separate file or in `<style/>` tags.

I also recommend you try the [web course](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web) on CodeCademy to learn most of everything you need to know about HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use a Background, it wouldn't be printed by some Browsers.

Best way to solve this is that you use relative (or absolute) Positioning on the Image Element.
But you must fix a little thing on the col- divs from Bootstrap. Basically they don't have any position Attribute, so you can't really use the position Attribute on the child elements.

So first, let's fix the positioning Inheritance problem:

```
.row > div { position:relative; }
```

Go for this CSS Rule as example to have it relative, you may use also `position: absolute` and or additionally `float:right`, but I think this should be fine, depends on your content. I've used 100px for your Image as example size, change this as you need.

```
.inkan_image { position:relative; top:0px; right:0px; width:100px; height:100px }
```

In Your HTML you just need to add your class to the Image.
By the way: I would position the Image as first element in your Content, as it will float or will be positioned on the right side and the content just swaps in then.

```
<img src='inkan.jpg' class='inkan_image'>
```